# How can this big method be refactored?

Tags: php, refactoring

I wrote a class for badge activation and it should be refactored now.
Are there any good advices, how should I refactor it's `trigger()` method?

The source of the class is in github:
https://github.com/heal25/ced/blob/master/models/BadgeActivator.php

The problematic method:

```
public function trigger($id, $data = []) {
    if (!$this->_uid) $this->setUid(Yii::app()->player->model->uid); //set default uid

    $activate = false;

    switch ($id) {
        //case 'login_1': $activate = true; break;
        case 'max_nrg_35': if ($data['energy_max'] >= 35) $activate = true; break;
        case 'max_nrg_100': if ($data['energy_max'] >= 100) $activate = true; break;
        case 'skill_35': if ($data['skill'] >= 35) $activate = true; break;
        case 'skill_100': if ($data['skill'] >= 100) $activate = true; break;
        case 'strength_35': if ($data['strength'] >= 35) $activate = true; break;
        case 'strength_100': if ($data['strength'] >= 100) $activate = true; break;
        case 'energy_drink': $activate = true; break;
        case 'level_10': if ($data['level'] >= 10) $activate = true; break;
        case 'level_100': if ($data['level'] >= 100) $activate = true; break;
        case 'dollar_50': if ($data['dollar'] >= 50) $activate = true; break;
        case 'dollar_5000': if ($data['dollar'] >= 5000) $activate = true; break;

        case 'travel_loc3': if ($data['water_id'] == 3) $activate = true; break;
        case 'travel_county2': if ($data['county_id'] == 2) $activate = true; break;
        case 'travel_county9': if ($data['county_id'] == 9) $activate = true; break;
        case 'routine_100': if ($data['routine'] >= 100) $activate = true; break;
        case 'loc_routine_4b': if ($data['water_id']==4 and $data['routine'] > 0) $activate = true; break;
        case 'loc_routine_13s': if ($data['water_id']==13 and $data['routine'] >= 3) $activate = true; break;
        case 'loc_routine_28s': if ($data['water_id']==28 and $data['routine'] >= 3) $activate = true; break;
        case 'loc_routine_37g': if ($data['water_id']==37 and $data['routine'] >= 9) $activate = true; break;
        case 'loc_routine_52b': if ($data['water_id']==52 and $data['routine'] > 0) $activate = true; break;
        case 'loc_routine_61s': if ($data['water_id']==61 and $data['routine'] >= 3) $activate = true; break;
        case 'loc_routine_71g': if ($data['water_id']==71 and $data['routine'] >= 9) $activate = true; break;
        case 'loc_routine_72e': if ($data['water_id']==72 and $data['routine'] >= 27) $activate = true; break;
        case 'loc_routine_46d': if ($data['water_id']==46 and $data['routine'] >= 81) $activate = true; break;
        case 'setpart_3': if ($data['cnt'] >= 3) $activate = true; break;
        case 'setpart_10': if ($data['cnt'] >= 10) $activate = true; break;
        case 'setpart_30': if ($data['cnt'] >= 30) $activate = true; break;
        case 'first_duel_win': if ($data['role'] == 'caller' and $data['winner'] == 'caller') $activate = true; break;
        case 'duel_success_100': if ($data['cnt'] >= 100) $activate = true; break;
        case 'duel_fail_100': if ($data['cnt'] >= 100) $activate = true; break;
        case 'duel_rate_40': if ($this->getSuccessRate(100, $data) <= 40) $activate = true; break;
        case 'duel_rate_25': if ($this->getSuccessRate(300, $data) <= 25) $activate = true; break;
        case 'duel_rate_10': if ($this->getSuccessRate(600, $data) <= 10) $activate = true; break;
        case 'duel_rate_60': if ($this->getSuccessRate(100, $data) >= 60) $activate = true; break;
        case 'duel_rate_75': if ($this->getSuccessRate(300, $data) >= 75) $activate = true; break;
        case 'duel_rate_90': if ($this->getSuccessRate(900, $data) >= 90) $activate = true; break;
        case 'duel_money_100': if ($data['dollar'] >= 100) $activate = true; break;
        case 'duel_money_1000': if ($data['dollar'] >= 1000) $activate = true; break;
        case 'duel_win_chance35': if ($data['winner'] and $data['chance'] <= 35) $activate = true; break;
        case 'duel_win_chance20': if ($data['winner'] and $data['chance'] <= 20) $activate = true; break;
        case 'duel_win_chance5': if ($data['winner'] and $data['chance'] <= 5) $activate = true; break;
        case 'duel_lose_chance65': if (!$data['winner'] and $data['chance'] >= 65) $activate = true; break;
        case 'duel_lose_chance80': if (!$data['winner'] and $data['chance'] >= 80) $activate = true; break;
        case 'duel_lose_chance95': if (!$data['winner'] and $data['chance'] >= 95) $activate = true; break;
        case 'duel_2h': if ($data['role'] == 'caller' and date('G')==2) $activate = true; break;
        case 'shop_item10': if (Yii::app()->player->model->owned_items >= 10) $activate = true; break;
        case 'shop_bait20': if (Yii::app()->player->model->owned_baits >= 20) $activate = true; break;
        case 'set_b': if ($data['id']==1) $activate = true; break;
        case 'set_s': if ($data['id']==2) $activate = true; break;
        case 'set_g': if ($data['id']==3) $activate = true; break;
        case 'set_sell_b': if ($data['id']==1) $activate = true; break;
        case 'set_sell_s': if ($data['id']==2) $activate = true; break;
        case 'set_sell_g': if ($data['id']==3) $activate = true; break;
        case 'club_join': $activate = true; break;
        case 'club_create': $activate = true; break;
        case 'club_members_8': if ($data['cnt'] >= 8) $activate = true; break;
        case 'login_days_7': if ($this->getLoginDays() >= 7) $activate = true; break;
        case 'login_days_30': if ($this->getLoginDays() >= 30) $activate = true; break;
        case 'login_days_60': if ($this->getLoginDays() >= 60) $activate = true; break;
        case 'win_contest': $activate = true; break;
    }

    if ($activate) {
       return $this->activate($id);
    }
    return false;
}
```

I can extract the activations for 'loc_routine_*' cases, but it isn't much.

Comment: Holy sweet mother of jesus, kill it with fire! I guess youre better off here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What is the main problem[s] of this method?

Comment: Make a function for each case, and a whitelisted array of function names; then do a call_user_func() if the $id is in your whitelist

Comment: Sorry, the question can be moved there. I saw [refactioring] tag here, so I though that can be here. If not, moderators, please move it to codereview.

Comment: sectus, tha main problem with this, that is is big, and there are duplicated code here.

Comment: having some structures like operation(op_name=nrg, in=max_nrg, out=energy_max) and a map of (operation, value) like (nrg, 35), (nrg, 100) you can easily parse your input id and select the right operation to perform with the right value as parameters.

Comment: There is too much hidden context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Yii, but from glancing over their docs, you could probably refactor the `trigger` method to make use of Yii Validators and the DI container. Something along these lines:

```
class BadgeActivator
…
    public function trigger($id, array $data)
    {
        $badgeValidator = $this->badgeValidators->findById($id);

        if ($badgeValidator->validate($data)) {
            $this->activate($id);
        }
    }
}
```

The `BadgeValidators` object is a simple collection of objects implementing the `BadgeValidator` interface. You need to inject this to your `BadgeActivator`.

```
class BadgeValidators
{
    private $validators = [];

    public function __construct(array $badgeValidators)
    {
        foreach ($badgeValidators as $badgeValidator) {
            $this->addBadgeValidator($badgeValidator);
        }
    }

    public function addBadgeValidator(BadgeValidator $badgeValidator)
    {
        $this->validators[$badgeValidator->getId()] = $badgeValidator;
    }

    public function findById($badgeId)
    {
        if (isset($this->validators[$badgeId])) {
            return $this->validators[$badgeId];
        }

        throw new BadgeValidatorNotFoundException(
            "No BadgeValidator found for badge id [$badgeId]"
        );
    }
}
```

The `BadgeValidator` interface is the contract all concrete validators need to obey. Their purpose is to map from `$data` to Yii's build in validators or to encapsulate additional/unique validation logic.:

```
interface BadgeValidator
{
    public function getId();
    public function validate($value = null);
}
```

A concrete Validator would then look like this:

```
class MaxEnergy35 implements BadgeValidator
{
    public function getId()
    {
        return 'max_nrg_35';
    }

    public function validate($value = null)
    {
        $validator = new yii\validators\IntegerValidator();
        $validator->min = 35;

        return $validator->validate($value['max_energy']);
    }
}
```

You could move the configuration for this class to the DI config as well, e.g. you could inject maxEnergy, validatorId and the Yii Validator. If you do that, you'll only have one class MaxEnergy instead of MaxEnergy35 and MaxEnergy100. For sake of simplicity, I'll keep it this way now.

Here is one with custom logic:

```
class DuelRate40 implements BadgeValidator
{
    public function getId()
    {
        return 'duel_rate_40';
    }

    public function validate()
    {
        return $this->getSuccessRate(100, $data) <= 40;
    }

    private function getSuccessRate($limit, array $data)
    {
        // moved from BadgeActivator
    }    
}
```

As you can see, it's trivial to make your BadgeValidators with custom logic and without using the Yii validators. In this particular case, I just moved the `getSuccessRate` rate method to the validator. You could easily see that it's misplaced on the BadgeActivator because it didn't have any cohesion to any class properties. Obviously, if you need this code in multiple validations, you could make it configurable again, so you have only one validator of that kind, instead of duplicating that method in each concrete one.

Now, for each `case` in your switch/case, simply add another concrete BadgeValidator and inject it to the BadgeValidators in the DIConfig.

In your `ced/config/main.php`:

```
// more config  …
components => [
    'badgeValidator' => [
        'class'=> 'application.components.BadgeValidator',
        'badgeValidators' => [
            ['class'=>'MaxEnergy35'],
            ['class'=>'MaxEnergy100'],
            ['class'=>'DuelRate40'],
            // more validators …
        ]
    ],
    // other components …
]
```

<sup>Note: I have no clue if this is the correct way to use Yii's DI config. I am just assuming from your file on GitHub. But I guess, you'll know how to change it if necessary.</sup>

And whenever you need to add a new Badge, you simply write the Validator and wire it up in the config. You will never need to touch the BadgeActivator again. This will also significantly lower the Cyclomatic Complexity of the BadgeActivator. And it's trivial to add Unit Tests for each of the components above.

Comment: Gordon, thank you for the very detailed explanation and code. I wish to design applications on level, like you. I'll rewrite my code (again) based on your post.